# How to Plot X/Y in Java Circuit Simulator

Tags: simulation, frequency-response, java, plot, falstad

Does anyone know how to select the Y variable when doing an X/Y Plot in [Java Circuit Simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/)? I tried many things and none have worked.

Comment: I an not familiar with this particular simulation package. To me Java is a programming language.  Please add a link to your question for a download or home page.

Comment: Click here: http://www.goo.gl/YkzseZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an X/Y plot in Falstad's Java Circuit Simulator, do the following:

1. Right click on the component that you would like to measure for your 'X' variable.
2. Select 'View in scope'.
3. Right click on the waveform and uncheck 'Show Voltage' or 'Show Current' to isolate the 'X' variable that you would like to plot.
4. Right click on the waveform again and select 'Plot X/Y'.
5. Place a scope probe where you would like to measure the voltage.
6. Right click on the waveform again and choose 'Select Y'.
7. Lastly, left click on the probe that you would like to use as your 'Y' axis.

**Note that you can only measure voltages on the 'Y' axis of an X/Y plot!**

Comment: you can also demonstrate VAR power (uWrms) in a capacitor with VI traces in XY mode and display FFT spectrum in a crude linear method.  Here I show a square to sine DAC converter with an FM sweep. http://tinyurl.com/y94z9l6c with scope showing peak values and autoscaling with Max option.

Comment: That's awesome! I haven't tried that before!